# Setting up MySQL issue under Eclipse PHP

Tags: php, mysql, eclipse, xampp

I have a snippet of code under the PHP file in Eclipse PHP.

```
$username = mysql_real_escape_string( $username );
```

It generates an error Warning:

> mysql_real_escape_string() [function.mysql-real-escape-string]: A link to the server could not be established in /web_development/php_work/new_test/test.php on line 37

Looks like the Eclipse PHP couldn't connect to the MySQL of XAMPP, so How do I fix that?

I added two lines

```
 @mysql_connect('localhost','root', '') or die('Could not connect to : ' . mysql_error());

    @mysql_select_db('test') or die( "-Unable to select database");
```

but Eclipse still throws me.

```
  mysql_connect() [<a href='function.mysql-connect'>function.mysql-connect</a>]: Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'
```

thx.

Comment: This method assumes a MySQL Link Identifer. Unless you can establish a connection without a username, host, or password, you'll need an explicit call to `mysql_connect()` before using this function.

Comment: To Jon,  Ok, I added the two MySQL connect statement but Eclipse still throws  Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock'

Comment: Why are you prefixing function calls with `@`? You should want to know if they raise any messages. If you are still unable to connect, you should speak with your system administrator. Connectivity is not a programming issue.

Comment: I am the admin as I am running on localhost  xampp &mysql.  I suspect it's some setup in Eclipse but no sure where.